# Using Swift to initialize CoreData from CSV

Tags: ios, swift, csv, core-data

I have data in few CSV files which needs to be initialized in CoreData. I want to know if there is any way to initialize CoreData tables with CSV file data.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Well, you could write some code to do it. It's possible, you just have to do it.

Comment: Simon take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Techies will be more inclined to help if you have taken the time to ask  your question, for instance what have you tried to do to solve this yourself? Do you have any code to show?

Answer (score 0):

Before going to the effort of storing your data in Core-Data I would first think about what are you using the data for? how big is it, etc.

If you are doing some simple reading from the csv file and the data is not large, then maybe it is not necessary to store in core-data.

If go down the core-data route, then you need to create the data models before you perform an import. So you are going to have to create tables and fields with the correct data types. Once you have that in place, then you can create some code to read the csv file in and then parse the data and create new instances of core data records to save and persist.
My suggestion would be to use a library like **Magical Record**, which does a lot of the heavy lifting with core-data.

Comment: The CSVs contain table data. I exported data from a sqlite database to CSV. I googled about using sqlite database in iOS but all results demonstrated using some library developed by individual, which I don't trust; so I decided to go with core data. The app will need to perform simple querying such as projection on data, nothing heavy like full joins.

Comment: I believe core data is sql-lite underneath(but optimized). In your case, you might be better off creating the tables in core data and then manually loading the csv file in and writing the records.